# Firebase analytics multiple apps in the same dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have multiple apps in my project. I want to demonstrate the data from all of these apps in one dashboard. For example if event_1 happens 3 times in app_1 and 4 times in app_2 the dashboard shows that event_1 happened 7 times.

I need a user friendly dashboard with a GUI (I know that BigQuery is an option, but it does not provide charts and is not easy to manipulate parameters).

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Did you report the feature request? If so, is there a public link for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Since May 2018 Google Analytics for Firebase has the ability to show analytics across all apps in the project, in addition to its previous ability to show analytics for each individual app.

Old answer:

<strike>Firebase Analytics shows the data for each app separately.</strike>

It currently does not have the ability to report across multiple apps in a project.

That is a reasonable feature request though, so you should definitely report it [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Can you elaborate (i.e. how to do it) your answer please?

Comment: The default in the console is now to report analytics across all apps. If you want analytics  for a specific app in the project, you can add a filter to do so.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Although, I still cannot see the analytics for all apps. On homepage here https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=2#/*****/reports/home, the first app is selected under Properties & App and I cannot see an option to select all. Is there another link that directs to all apps? I am not sure if we are talking about the same things here.

Comment: It seems that Firebase Analytics no longer support showing analytics for separate apps. Now, there is no app-based filter.

Comment: Is app based filter removed from dashboard?